# Closed graph implies boundedness?

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Let $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$. If $G_f$ is the graph of $f$ and $G_f$ is closed, does it imply that $f$ is bounded?

Comment: Before you ask: Closedness of the graph does not even imply continuity, though that would at least be an implication that one might expect.

Answer (score 5):

No. Take
$$
f:(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\longmapsto x_1.
$$